# I2C Level translation

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

In our current design, we have two devices which communicate with each other using I2C. But their I2C logic levels are different, so we need to use a level translation?
Can I use a simple level translator for this?
I have chosen this part MAX13003
http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX13000E-MAX13005E.pdf

Comment: there are different ways for I2C level translation....from using simple MOSFET's to ic'S  like PCA9517(just ex)....just google "simple I2C level translator"...lot's of links are available....

Comment: Are you really sure the logic levels are different? The logic threshold levels are specified by IIC, so 5 V and 3.3 V devices, for example, can co-exist on the same IIC bus as long as the lines are only pulled up to the lowest supply voltage.

Comment: 'logic-level' isn't the right tag for this. Removed same.

Answer (score 3):

It can be easy to level shift the I<sup>2</sup>C signals between two voltage domains using any one of a number of different buffer parts that are made specifically for this purpose. However for most applications there is another discrete solution that works very well as shown below.

[image]

This solution will be lower cost to implement as long as you do not need additional buffering of the I<sup>2</sup>C bus. If buffering for long buses or excess capacitance or going between boards is needed then it is recommended to look into the chip type buffer solution.

You can gain additional information and understanding from the NXP (formerly Philips) application note on [Bi-directional Level Shifters](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

There are parts out there there that are designed for exactly this application. These will also give you some sweet bonuses like ESD protection.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9306.pdf

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scps221b/scps221b.pdf

...etc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that type will work because the direction will not be properly determined. Also I2C is open-drain, and that is push- pull. So I suggest you un-choose that part.

Refer to NXP [AN10441](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf) for appropriate methods. NXP (née Philips) invented [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C).

[image]

Comment: There is an older version of that paper too (longer version). [AN97055 Bi-directional level shifter for
I2C-bus and other systems](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf),  New shorter version [AN10441 
Level shifting techniques in I2C-bus design](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf)